# Solr: 404 error with getting admin page

Tags: solr

I've installed Solr on my Ubuntu to this path

```
/opt/solr/solr-4.10.2
```

After installing I started Solr:

```
sudo bin/solr start from /opt/solr/solr-4.10.2 directory
```

As I can understand it started successfully

```
Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8983 [/]  
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=8385). Happy searching!
```

But when I try to get to admin page

```
http://localhost:8983/solr
```

I got 404 error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404
Problem accessing /solr. Reason:

    Not Found

Powered by Jetty://
```

Do you have any suggestion what's going wrong and where to look in order to fix this problem?

Comment: If you just access http://localhost:8983/ you should see a list of registered contexts - check if there's any present

Comment: What I got

Contexts known to this server are:

    /solr ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/opt/solr/solr-4.10.2/example/solr-webapp/webapp/},/opt/solr/solr-4.10.2/example/webapps/solr.war [failed]

Comment: Check your log for any startup issues for Solr - doesn't seem like the context is able to start up like it should.

Comment: This seems to happen if the "wrong" Java version is used to start Solr. I requested https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10650 to improve that solr no longer makes a secret out of this.

Answer (score 1):

Since this error can be caused by a lot of things, you need to access the log file and debug the execution.

First of all, open your Node log file, located in `/opt/solr/solr-4.10.2/node1/log` and look for something weird (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for Errors).

Generally, this error occurs when you have a mismatch between the Solr required Java JDK and your current Java JDK.

When I had this problem, I found in the log file the following error message `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/solr/servlet/SolrDispatchFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` and realized the problem was the **java version**.

To solve this, try to change the current JDK, using the command `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`.

If the error still occurs, try to uninstall all unused JDK's, **because Solr is getting the wrong path**.

The **final solution** to this issue is to open the file `/opt/solr/solr-4.10.2/solar.in.sh` and edit the SOLR_JAVA_HOME, writing the right JDK path (e.g `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0`)

**Disclosure**: the secret is look in the log file and figure out what is causing the issue.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try:

http://localhost:8983/solr/index.html

[solr's web.xml]

```
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>LoadAdminUI</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.LoadAdminUiServlet</servlet-class>
```